# Xubuntu Session Issues: Multiple Windows, Positioning, Workspaces

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, session

I have recently switched to Xubuntu as my environment for coding work, and I'm quite satisfied. However, I would like to set it up in a way where I only need to start the computer and have the session be exactly the same as it was when I logged out. This would be hugely helpful with my setup (coding on one workspace, communication on the other, multiple terminal consoles open and arranged with IDE etc.).

However, I ran into three issues with the Xubuntu/XFCE session manager:

1) When I have multiple windows of the same application open, it does not always seem to open them all back up. For instance, with Chromium, it will only open one window instead of several, and Chromium will offer to restore the browser session.

2) Some windows switch their positioning. For instance, I have one console at the top and one at the bottom of the screen, split in the middle, for some work. When I log back in, they are both at the top of the workspace.

3) Some windows even seem to be switching workspaces. I am currently using the Sublime 2 Text Editor, and it just moves from workspace 1 to workspace 2 when I log back in.

Is there any way to fix these issues or will I just have to live with doing it manually each time?

Comment: I just started running into another issue, which rolls up the Chrome window on restore, so I need to roll it back down. Also, programs in the system tray will not be minimized anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I saw similar problems in xfce on openSUSE 12.3 and openSUSE 13.1: all windows end up in the same workspace, saved session forgot changes, etc. My solution was to use devilspie for defining placement rules and then write a small startup script.

http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie